# delete all exept : "extensionAttribute3":"M" or "extensionAttribute1":"P" and so on

Tags: search, trim

I need retain only all the posibles "extensionAttribute1":"" and delete the rest fom big file , where "" content is always changing. thx in advance for your help

I expect to see all records that contein : "extensionAttribute1":"G"  or "extensionAttribute1":"PW" , etc